# Fetching data from json in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm trying to use a `.json` file from a GitHub repository. ([Here](https://github.com/kennymkchan/funko-pop-data))

I created a function and it should get data from this `.json` file in my project.

```
private func fetchData() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "funko_pop", withExtension: "json") {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Errore nella richiesta: \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Dati mancanti.")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode([FunkoPop].self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    funkoPops = decodedData
                }
            } catch {
                print("Errore nella decodifica JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    } else {
        print("URL non valido.")
    }
}
```

Here's my struct:

```
struct FunkoPop: Codable {
    let handle: String
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let series: [String]
}
```

Comment: What is the question? At least replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error` to get a meaningful error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Junior dev and I still make lots of mistakes! 

Here's the error I get: 

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "image", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"image\", intValue: nil) (\"image\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: In the JSON there is no key `image`, maybe you want `imageName`. The names of the struct members must match the JSON keys respectively.

Comment: I tried it, but I still have the same issue. Here's my struct:

struct FunkoPop: Codable {
    let handle: String
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let series: [String]
}

Comment: Wait a minute, if the file is in the bundle you have to use `Data(contentsOf:` instead of `URLSession`, or if you want to load the data from the Github repository you have to specify an `https` URL.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a valid `@State var funkoPops: [FunkoPop]` declared, try this example code,
to read your file from your project:

```
 private func fetchData() {
     guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "funko_pop", withExtension: ".json") else {
         print("---> url error")
         return
     }
     do {
         let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
         let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([FunkoPop].self, from: jsonData)
       // print(decodedData.count)
         funkoPops = decodedData
     } catch {
         print("---> decoding error: \(error)")
     }
 }
```

EDIT-1:

Here is my full test code, to fetch and decode the json data directly from github or from a file
in your project. Works well for me, tested on ios17 devices, MacCatalyst and MacOS.

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI

struct FunkoPop: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var handle: String
    var imageName: String
    var title: String
    var series: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case handle, imageName, title, series
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var funkoPops = [FunkoPop]()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(funkoPops.count)")
        List(funkoPops){ item in
            Text(item.title)
        }
        .task {
            await fetchDataGithub()  // <--- from github repo
        }
//            .onAppear {
//                fetchDataFile()  // <--- from local file
//            }
    }
    
    func fetchDataGithub() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kennymkchan/funko-pop-data/master/funko_pop.json") else {
            print("---> url error")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([FunkoPop].self, from: data)
            print(decodedData.count)
            funkoPops = decodedData
        } catch {
            print("---> decoding error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchDataFile() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "funko_pop", withExtension: ".json") else {
            print("---> url error")
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([FunkoPop].self, from: jsonData)
            print(decodedData.count)
            funkoPops = decodedData
        } catch {
            print("---> decoding error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did my answer not work for someone? I tested my answer thouroughly on ios devices and macCatalyst.
 Please explain what is not working. If I got the question wrong, that you want to directly download the 
 data from the github repo, then I can show that code too.

Comment: updated my answer with my test code, to fetch the json data from the github repository as well as a local file.